# what is the symbol $⊭$ in logic?

Tags: logic, terminology

I know that $⊨$ symbol is **entails** symbol and $A⊨B$ means that if A is True then B must be True.

> But I'm confused about the $⊭$ symbol. which one is it?
>
> - $A⊭B$ means if A is true then B is False? = $A⊨¬B$
> - $A⊭B$ means the Trueness of A is not any guarantee for B?
> - $A⊭B$ means if A is False then B must be True? = $¬A⊨B$

thank you in advance.

Comment: Clearly not the third, as that is consistent with $A⊨B$

Comment: @Henry, one and three are consistent with that. the problem was I couldn't find any resource for it on the web! all is just about $⊨$.

Comment: @Peymanmohsenikiasari No, option 1 is not consistent with $A \vDash B$. If $A \vDash B$, then all assignments which make $A$ true must also make $B$ true, but then $\neg B$ can never be the case.

Comment: @Henry Oh! my mistake. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A \vDash B$ means

> For all assignments $v$, if $A$ is true under $v$, then $B$ is true under $v$.

$A \not \vDash B$ simply is the (meta-logical) negation of this statement, that is

> Not for all assignments $v$ it is the case that if $A$ is true under $v$, then $B$ is true under $v$

which is equivalent to

> There is at least one assignment $v$ such that $A$ is true under $v$ but $B$ is not

which means your second option is the right one.

The other two options (1 and 3) are notated in the way you already figured out by yourself.

Comment: well, so if $A⊭B$ then A must be satisfiable I think. nice, thank you.

Comment: @Peymanmohsenikiasari Correct. Because if $A$ is not satisfiable (= is a contradiction), then it entails any formula.

Comment: To emphasize, $A\nvDash B$ literally means "it is not the case that $A\vDash B$". That is, it is simply the meta-logical negation of $A\vDash B$. That is why there is not special discussion of it. We can, as lemontree does, work out a more pleasant, equivalent formulation.